# How to add moving Text overlay on Video by moviepy Python

Tags: python, moviepy

I want to add moving Text overlay from (Left to Right) or (Right to Left) on top of any full-length video by using moviepy Python module.

I tried the below code, it worked on short videos like 5 sec, and 10 sec but it's not cover long-length videos like 1/2+ minutes. How to do this for all types of video duration/length like 5/10/30+ minutes.

```
from moviepy.editor import *

video_file = VideoFileClip('video.mp4')

def position(t):
    return (45*t, 0*t)

add_text = TextClip("www.YouTube.com",fontsize=30,color="red").set_position(position).set_duration(video_file.duration)

final = CompositeVideoClip([video_file,add_text])

final.write_videofile("test.mp4")
```